# Windows 7 can't find my GPT drive

Tags: windows-7, gpt

I added a new 2TB drive to my system yesterday. I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.

After booting up, Windows formatted the drive and suggested I format with GPT. I said yes, the format went fine, and a new drive letter was assigned. Everything is working so far.

I started to transfer my files onto the new file folder - this all went fine as well. However the next time I rebooted, Windows couldn't find the drive!

Attached is a screenshot from Disk Management. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As this is a new disk, it might simply have broken down.
As it is probably still under warranty, I would suggest to exchange or be reimbursed.

I would also note that in your case, GPT as far as I know doesn't offer an advantage over MBR, as MBR can support 2 TB. GPT is newer, so it could have some compatibility issues.

Comment: GPT is a far saner partitioning scheme. We should all be jumping off MBR disks as soon as possible. 2TiB limit and 4 primary partition limit are only the tip of the iceberg.